# How to install Node v10 on m2 max on macbook pro 16

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

When I run nvm install 10, I get this error. I have checked that I have python3 installed. I am also able to nvm install 16 and up without issue.

```
Downloading and installing node v10.24.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.24.1/node-v10.24.1-darwin-arm64.tar.xz...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404                                                                                                                                                                                                    

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.24.1/node-v10.24.1-darwin-arm64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /Users/sadeeb/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v10.24.1-darwin-arm64/node-v10.24.1-darwin-arm64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v10.24.1/node-v10.24.1.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v10.24.1/node-v10.24.1.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/Users/sadeeb/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1 <
./configure: line 3: exec: python: not found
nvm: install v10.24.1 failed!
```

I've reinstalled homebrew, reinstalled python, double checked the version of NVM is up to date, and have ran through the troubleshooting provided by GPT. Seems like I am unable to get this version of node running. I have also specified 10.24.1 for install, as well as specified version 10.18.1.

Comment: Node prior to v16 was never released for ARM64, and v10 is well out of support anyway.

Comment: Right, but unfortunately I am required to test my code on v10 for the project I am working on, I was hoping there was a workaround.

Comment: Given the above it seems pointless to still be testing on Node 10, but you could use e.g. a Docker container.

Comment: I agree some projects use old versions, try using nvm this link might help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-node-version-manager

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal in Rosetta2 as the older then node v15 versions can't be installed in arm based mac so follow these steps
Go to Application -> Right click on terminal app -> Get Info -> Select "Open using Rosetta" -> Restart Terminal
In Terminal, write -> arch -x86_64 zsh

now follow the installation of the nvm using this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-node-version-manager)